# realloc pointer change when out of function

Tags: c++, arrays, realloc

i am starting homework about dynamic array, first, I have a 2 dimensional array :

```
int initializeInfo[3][4] ={{77,68,0,0},{96,87,89,78},{70,90,86,0}};
```

and use pointer to store it:

```
int **ptr = (int**)malloc(3*sizeof(int));
int size = 0;
for(int i =0;i<3;i++){
    addInitiazeInfo(ptr,initializeInfo[i],size);
}
```

here is function addInitiazeInfo:

```
void addInitiazeInfo(int**& ptr, int arr[],int& size){
    ptr[size] = (int*)malloc(4*sizeof(int));
    if(ptr[size] == NULL){
        return;
    }
    ptr[size] = arr;
    size++;
}
```

It's run OK! The 2 dimensional array is store by ptr pointer.[image]

And I want to add new row, I think realloc is needed, then I try:

```
int arr[] = {3,4,5,6};
size++;            
ptr = (int**)realloc(ptr,size * sizeof( int ) );
ptr[size-1] = (int*)malloc(4*sizeof(int));
ptr[size-1] = arr;
```

But I think this is my trouble, the output make me hard to know how it happend:
[image]

please help me, thanks everyone

Comment: I dont think you realize what `ptr[size] = arr;` is doing

Comment: `int **ptr = (int**)malloc(3*sizeof(int));` is wrong (and so is the realloc)) . BTW: C does not have references. Maybe you mean C++ ?

Comment: The defined type for ptr is `int **ptr;`, so it points to a pointer, (or to the first member of an array of pointers) So, you should allocate `3 * sizeof (int*)` chars for it. AND: mixing C and C++ _really_ is a bad habit.

Comment: When your program contains `**&` it doesn't matter whether you make it work or not, your program is unreadable either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
ptr[size] = arr;
```

You are essentially assigning the address of `arr`, to `ptr[size]`. This means that the memory you just allocated is lost and successfully leaked.

You want to manually copy element by element or use something like `memcpy`. It is likely this might fix your issue, depending on the rest of your code.